# How to do condition on form html (ruby)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

i have a form with the inputs and there is also a checkbox in this form. when i click on this box it shows another form under it (clicking the checkbox is optional), the second form may not be filled. the problem is that when i did not insert the responses on the second form, when i get the last result (PDF) it shows me blanks in place of answers (of the second form).so if it is filled i want it to show the results, in the event that is not filled in, i do not want to see the inputs for the answer empty

**This is my code**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employee_code" >first name<span class="necessary-field">*</span></label>
        <%= f.text_field :name_en, :value => @employee.first_name , :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employee_code" >last name<span class="necessary-field">*</span></label>
        <%= f.text_field :name_last, :value => @employee.last_name , :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employee_code" >Country<span class="necessary-field">*</span></label>
        <%= f.text_field :Country_en, :value => (Country.find(@employee.nationality_id).name unless @employee.nationality_id.nil?) , :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  <hr class="label-underline"></hr>

  <div id="second_form">
  
 <%= check_box_tag(:name, :value , false, {:onchange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:controller => "form_two", :action => "done"}
  )}
"})%><%= "second_form" %>
</div>
```

Comment: so i need to do a condition on the checkbox (if null dont show the inputs of the results on file PDF)

Comment: Just use `<% if condition %>` around the whole HTML that needs to be conditional.

Check for the presence of the value in `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Nested form elements are not permitted in HTML - and this isn't just a a case of the validator whining. The behavior in that case is not standarized and it may behave irratically. Take this example:

```
<form action="/foo">
  <form action="/bar">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</form>
```

Is clicking the button going to send the request to `/foo` or `/bar`? Maybe both?

What you can do is have a set of nested inputs on the page which are initially hidden and then displayed when you click the button:

```erb
<%= form_with(model: @thing) do |form| %>
  <%= form.check_box_tag(:foo, class: "visibility_toggle", data: { target: "second_form" }) %>
  <fieldset id="second_form" class="hidden">
    <%= form.fields_for(:other_thing) do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_input :foo %> 
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

```javascript
document.addEventListener("change", function(event){
  if (!event.target.matches(".visibility_toggle")) return;
  document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.target)
          .classList
          .toggle('hidden');
});
```

These are really just normal inputs but `fields_for` adds a extra set of brackets to the `name` attribute so that they are grouped in a hash in the parameters.

You should really just consider if you really want to mash everything into a single form. You could instead redirect to step 2 after the user fills in the basic information which would be better for accessibilty and may gave a better user experience overall.

See [Rails guides - Building complex forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).